# How to get Key and Values in order from XML document

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

Here I'm parsing a given XML document and obtaining the element node keys and values. However the order in which I get these values is in random order. How can I get it in order from top of document to bottom.

Example: [MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP, MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP, MonthCdPP, etc...]

Is it because of my data structure? I am converting from Map to List.

XML Document:

```
<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
  <ReturnData>
    <IRS1095A uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="69dc9dd5-5415-4ee4-a199-19b2dbb701be">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>SEPTEMBER</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
    </IRS1095A>
    <IRS1040>
      <IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>1</IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>
      <WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>22000</WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>
      <TotalExemptionsCnt>1</TotalExemptionsCnt>
      <AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>22000</AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>
    </IRS1040>
  </ReturnData>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <SelfSelectPINGrp>
      <PrimaryBirthDt>1970-01-01</PrimaryBirthDt>
    </SelfSelectPINGrp>
    <Filer>
      <PrimarySSN>555-11-2222</PrimarySSN>
      <PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
        <ResidentStateInfoPP uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
          <ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>CA</ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>
        </ResidentStateInfoPP>
      </PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
    </Filer>
  </ReturnHeader>
</Return>
```

Code:

```
@Test
public void testGetXMLModelData() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("xmlDir/example.xml");
    Model m = getXMLModelData(f);

    logger.debug("Models Keys: "+m.getInputs());
    logger.debug("Models Values: "+m.getValues());
}

public Map<String, String> p(File file) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

    while(xr.hasNext()) {

        int e = xr.next();
        if (e == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
            //Further implementation
        } 
    }
    return map;
}



public Model getXMLModelData(File f) throws Exception { 

    Model model = new Model();

    Map<String,String> map = p(f);
    List<String> listKeys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());

    model.setInputs(listKeys);
    model.setValues(listValues); 


    return model;
}
```

Here is the class I defined as Model:

```
public class Model {

    public static final int INPUTS_ROW = 5;

    private String topic;
    private List<String> inputs;
    private List<String> values;

    public Model() {
        inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }


    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public List<String> getInputs() {
        return inputs;
    }

    public void setInputs(List<String> inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the HashMap, since that data structure lists in unordered fashion. The solution is to use a `LinkedHashMap` which will preserve the insertion order into the map, it scans document from top to bottom.